# Связывание коллекций Mongo DB

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, nosql, meteor

Есть две коллекции:

```
Trains = new Mongo.Collection('trains');

Passengers = new Mongo.Collection('passengers');
```

Одна содержит данные о поездах, другая - данные о пассажирах. В каждом документе поезда есть поле `numberOfPassengers`. У каждого пассажира есть поле `train`. Мне нужно, чтобы `numberOfPassengers` каждого поезда хранило текущее количество пассажиров, с определенным полем `train`. Иными словами:

```
Trains.find({name: 'redTrain'}).numberOfPassengers = Passengers.find({train: 'redTrain').count();
```

Каким образом возможно связать две эти коллекции подобным образом? Чтобы в документе одной коллекции могло динамически храниться количество элементов из другой коллекции.

Comment: С версии 3.2 монги aggregation framework поддерживает подобие джоинов. Т.е. данные не будут хранится (дублироваться) в другой коллекции, но вы их будете получать в момент запроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB не предназначен для связывания коллекций, как таблиц в SQL базах данных.

В вашем случае, лучше всего хранить полный список объектов пассажиров в коллекции trains.

```
{
"_id" : "0018ff5cb7b1fab5d0980c0bebfb26ec",
"train_number" : "324234",
"title" : "Number One",
"passengers" : [ 
          {
            "name" : "Robert Willson",
            "passport" : "238476384"
          }
               ]
}
```

Если вы хотите разнести данные по коллекциям, то можно хранить в коллекции trains _id пассажиров.

```
{
"_id" : "0018ff5cb7b1fab5d0980c0bebfb26ec",
"train_number" : "324234",
"title" : "Number One",
"passengers" : ["0018ff5cb7b1fab5d09234i798324",
                "0018ff5cb7b1f21387637841324ff" 
               ]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за скорый ответ. Тоже сначала реализовал так, но проблема в следующем. Реактивный протокол, по которому связываются клиент и сервер, умеет обновлять поля монго-документа только 1 уровня вложенности. Другими словами, если хранить список пассажиров в каждом поезде, то при изменении данных одного пассажира, передаваться будет весь объект passengers. Отсюда и возник вопрос.

Comment: Хранение в коллекции _id пассажиров кажется рабочим решением. У пассажира должно быть поле train_id. Останется только в методах добавления/удаления пассажиров обновлять поле passengers у поезда с пассажирским train_id, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, все верно. Проверяете _id пассажира в списке passengers и делаете обновление.